# Looking for a suitable smooth weight function

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am interested in a smooth weight function $w_P(x_1, x_2) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that
we have $w_P(x_1, x_2) = 1$ if $ \|(x_1, x_2)\| \leq P$ and goes to $0$ as $ \|(x_1, x_2)\|$ gets larger, and it satisfies
$$
\sum_{ \substack{ \|(x_1, x_2)\| > P \\ x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}} } w_P(x_1, x_2) \leq C
$$
for some constant $C$ independent of $P$.
Could someone possibly give me an example of such weight function? (if such a function actually exists)

Thank you very much!

PS Here $\| \|$ is a sup norm.

Comment: Do you really mean to have the sum there?  If so, you're trying to sum over an uncountable set.  Perhaps you mean to have an integral?

Comment: @Glitch Thanks! I meant sum over the integer points. It has been fixed!

Comment: Something funny with your quantifiers. I think you want to say that there exists $C>0$ such that for all $P>0,$ there exists a weight function $w_P$ with the properties you described.

Comment: @zhw. True. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D = \{(x_1, x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid \|(x_1, x_2)\| \leq P\}$. Then $D$ is compact, so for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a smooth [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) which is equal to $1$ on $D$ and equal to $0$ at all points which are at least distance $\varepsilon$ away from $D$ (in the given norm). By taking $\varepsilon$ small enough, you can force the function to be zero at any integer point not in $D$.